# IP whitelisting on Azure WebApp for AppInitialization

Tags: asp.net, azure, initialization, ip-address, whitelist

Could not find information about the IP whitelisting for Azure WebApps that have app initialization section.

If you have config section like this

```
  <system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization>
      <add initializationPage="/my-initialization.aspx" />      
    </applicationInitialization>
  </system.webServer>
```

For on-prem apps hosted on IIS you need to allow 127.0.0.1; do you need to do the same for webapps?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, the question is a bit unclear, I`m going to add a bit of context.

Application is already have some ip restrictions using "Networking" -> "Access Restrictions". With just a handful allowed ips and the last rule being "deny all".

I tested this feature with the clear application without any restrictions and it is working just fine. With the real application I do not want to configure the extensive tracing to be able to see successful calls to my warm-up pages.

I was following this article to configure everything for my testing: https://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/

Comment: Have you tried using it without the IP whitelist? And it didn't work? Did you try it with the IP address allowed?

Comment: @juunas Updated my question

Answer (score 2):

If the question is with applicationInitialization, do we need to implement ipSecurity as well, the anwser is no.

**Application Initialization Configuration Information**

With the AppInit feature, as new web app instances are added into rotation, we ensure that the Application Initialization module reports that the site is fully warmed up before sending it requests from the frontend. To use the feature, add an applicationInitialization section to your web.config like so:

```html
<system.webServer>        
<applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="/Content/warmup.html"> 
                  <add initializationPage="/api/values/100" /> 
          </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

You can have multiple initialization pages, and the AppInit module will ensure that all 
 of them return 200 before declaring the site officially warmed up. Meanwhile, you can 
 (optionally) use the remapManagedRequestsTo attribute to have a friendly page showing 
 that the site is still warming up.  Thanks to the AppInit feature, this page will not be 
 visible to customers while adding new instances into rotation, however if a process 
 crashes for whatever reason and enters AppInit again, it will come into play.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the remapManagedRequestsTo attribute. Handy. But I updated my question with some extra context. My app is already has ip restrictions configured and the bottom rule is "deny all"